# ¿setAttribute pone atributos solo en minuscula?

Tags: javascript

Estoy haciendo un constructor de `hmtl` con `JavaScript` y tengo que integrar los atributos de los elementos con ello.

Hay dos elementos que necesito que tengan el atributo en mayúscula, porque sino, no funcionan.

Hasta ahora todas las pruebas que hice me dan resultado negativo, no puedo poner un ejemplo mínimo verificable ya que son pruebas con import y export enrte más de 20 archivos. No sería lógico pues.

Es una pregunta solamente teórica.

¿SetAttribute establece SOLO atributos en minúsculas?

Comment: Puedes poner un ejemplo como el de [la respuesta de @PabloLozano](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/450739/54039); aunque pongas `ATRIBUTO="valor"` y se convierta en `atributo="valor"` aún puedes acceder a él con `elemento.getAttribute('ATRIBUTO')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HTML es un lenguaje *case-insensitive*. Esto significa que no distingue entre mayúsculas y minúsculas para los nombres de las etiquetas o de los atributos. Los valores guardados en los atributos sí distinguen entre mayúsculas y minúsculas, para no perder información:

```js
let div = document.getElementById('prueba');
let div2 = document.getElementById('Prueba');
//las IDs son distintas
console.log(div.innerHTML, div2.innerHTML);
```

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<!-- Da igual cómo pontas el nombre de la etiqueta o del atributo-->
<dIv id="prueba">Texto 1</DIV>
<dIv ID="Prueba">texto 2</Div>
```

Por ese motivo `setAttribute(name, value)` transforma siempre el nombre a minúsculas. De la [documentación de MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute#sintaxis):

> ## `Element.setAttribute(name, value);`
>
> ### Parámetros
>
> **name**
>
> Un DOMString indicando el nombre del atributo cuyo valor se va a cambiar. El nombre del atributo se convierte automáticamente en minúsculas cuando setAttribute() se llama sobre un elemento HTML en un documento HTML.
>
> **value**
>
> Un DOMString que contenga el valor que asignar al atributo. Cualquier valor indicado que no sea una cadena de texto se convierte automáticamente en una cadena de texto.

Comment: Muchas gracias, me resolviste la duda! As allways :3